# logic of variable in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have some lines of code :
why print 'undefined' and 'B' on my browser . Can you explain for me?

```
var x = 'A';

function func(){
  document.write(x);
  var x = "B";
  document.write(x);
};

func();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's [JavaScript Hoisting](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp). In your example `x` inside that function is hoisted. In JavaScript, variable declarations are only hoisted, NOT their initializations.

**Update:**

Regarding ES6, `const` and `let` declarations are not hoisted.